# Stuck and unable to sign in after deleting google play games data

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using Google Play Services for my libgdx game. I created some dummy achievements to test and later wanted to remove them. On my phone I went to Google Play Games -> Settings -> Delete Play Games Data -> Deleted data from my game.

After going back into my game, I noticed that the game thought I was still signed in. I use the following code to check if a user is signed in:

```
@Override
public boolean isSignedIn(){
    return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(androidLauncher) != null;
}
```

If the user is not signed in, I try to sign them in silently

```
private void signInSilently() {

    signedInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(androidLauncher,
        new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    signedInAccount = task.getResult();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

If I can't sign them in silenty. I create a new intent and have them manually sign in and give access to the app:

```
    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        showSignedInDialog();
    }
```

The problem is, after deleting the Play Games Data, my method `isSignedIn` is always returning true. However, when I try to do something like display achievements, I get the following error:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: The user must be signed in to make this API call.
```

Code for showing achievements:

```
@Override
public void showAchievements(){

    androidLauncher.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isSignedIn()) {
                loadingView.showLoadingView();
                Games.getAchievementsClient(androidLauncher, signedInAccount)
                    .getAchievementsIntent()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {                                    
                             androidLauncher
                                    .startActivityForResult(intent, RC_ACHIEVEMENT_UI);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Logger.error(e);
                        }
                    })
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

I'm curious as to why this is happening. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin), my `isSignedIn` method should be working correctly. However, because I'm getting the error that I'm getting when I actually try to make an API call, it appears that the method is not working. I can only assume that all of this is stemming from me deleting my Play Games Data as everything worked fine up until that point.

**Something else I want to note** - I tried having my `isSignedIn` method return false to force a silent sign in. My silent sign in returned the following error:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: 8:
```

I did a bit of research and found a [bug report](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/358). It looks like a status code of 8 is [an Internal Error](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#INTERNAL_ERROR). Google at least seems to [be aware of the issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/358#issuecomment-37755).

**Update**: After having my `isSignedIn` method return false, and after disabling my silent sign in, I forced a manual sign in. After forcing the manual sign in, and signing in, it now works. However, I won't be able to do that for users if they run into the same issue. They would be stuck as the `isSignedIn` method seems to always return true after deleting the Play Games Data.

Comment: Can you try clearing the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and what worked for me was enabling the Google Drive API for my project. Not sure why this worked, but it did.

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis, then open the "Library" menu option. From there, search for "Drive" and click on the "Google Drive API" item. You should then see an enable button.